Python multiprocessing apply_async with callback does not update the dictionary data structure
I'm trying to count all the tokens in a catalog. Due to the large amount of document, I'd like to do this counting using multiprocessing (or any other parallel calculation tool that you're free to mention). My problem is that naive construction does not work.
Here the minimal example I constructed
import multiprocessing
import random

def count_tokens(document):
    counter = dict()
    for token in document:
        if token in counter:
            counter[token] += 1
        else:
            counter[token] = 1
    return counter

tokens = ['tok'+str(i) for i in range(int(9))]
catalog = [random.choices(tokens, k=8) for _ in range(100)]

token_counts = {token: 0 for token in tokens}

def callback(result):
    global token_counts
    for token, count in result.items():
        token_counts[token] += count
    return token_counts

with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
    for document in catalog:
        pool.apply_async(count_tokens, args=(document,), callback=callback)

and the problem is that the returned token_counts is not the same as the un-parallel calculation
token_counts = {token: 0 for token in tokens}
for document in catalog:
    callback(count_tokens(document))

To be sure I constructed the complete script
import multiprocessing
import random

def count_tokens(document):
    counter = dict()
    for token in document:
        if token in counter:
            counter[token] += 1
        else:
            counter[token] = 1
    return counter

tokens = ['tok'+str(i) for i in range(int(9))]
catalog = [random.choices(tokens, k=8) for _ in range(100)]

token_counts = {token: 0 for token in tokens}

def callback(result):
    global token_counts
    for token, count in result.items():
        token_counts[token] += count
    return token_counts

with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
    for document in catalog:
        pool.apply_async(count_tokens, args=(document,), callback=callback)
        
count_multiprocessing = dict(**token_counts)
print(count_multiprocessing)

token_counts = {token: 0 for token in tokens}
for document in catalog:
    callback(count_tokens(document))

count_onecpu = dict(**token_counts)
print(count_onecpu)

for token, count in count_onecpu.items():
    assert count == count_multiprocessing[token]
for token, count in count_multiprocessing.items():
    assert count == count_onecpu[token]

that always end up with an assertion error at home (Python 3.10.9 if that matters).

The error is due to the fact that you're using apply_async but not waiting for all processes to terminate.
Do the multiprocessing part like this:
pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
try:
    for document in catalog:
        pool.apply_async(count_tokens, (document,), callback=callback)
finally:
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

You could also consider constructing token_counts based on the returned values from the async process(es). In that way you wouldn't have concerns of the use of global variables

Thank you very much for your answer. Indeed it works. My mistake was the pissing of close and join ... I thought it was managed by the context manager...
By the way, the joining is quite long now. Is there a way to speed up this step ?

"You could also consider constructing token_counts based on the returned values from the async process(es)" : I do not understand this part of your answer, could you give an illustration in my simple case please ?

@FraSchelle The realtime delay between close and join is entirely due to the number of subprocesses that are running. My answer uses apply_async only because that's what you were using in your original code. That may not be the most appropriate technique for your use-case.

Counter
You might have employed
defaultdict(int).
But the even more obvious thing to do would be
"from collections import
Counter".
Then
def count_tokens(document):
    counter = dict()
    for token in document:
        if token in counter:
            counter[token] += 1
        else:
            counter[token] = 1
    return counter

would become simply return Counter(document).
mutex
Your callback() does not acquire a lock.
So the {read, increment, write} results are not robust.
If you wish to understand this in more detail,
write the sorted resulting tokens to per-document output files,
and subsequently gather those files together and diff
the single-core versus multiprocessing versions.
Please note the module offers more than one way
for an application to relax the task processing
ordering constraints.
overhead
You want the pool to be serializing short pathnames
sent down to the worker processes, which will then open()
the file and read in a giant document.
What you don't
want is for the parent process to hold onto giant documents,
which must then be laboriously serialized and sent down a pipe
to each worker child process.
